# PHP require 2 consecutive identical punctuation characters using regex

Tags: php, regex

```
("#.*^(?=.*[[:lower:]]{2})(?=.*[[:upper:]])(?=.*[[:digit:]])(?=.*[[:punct:]]{2}$).*$#"))
```

I have created this regular expression to require specific items in a password. All of them are working except the last step which needs to require the same punctuation character twice and for those characters to be identical.

Im stuck on this.. can anyone else please?

Comment: If I may ask... why would you ever restrict a password like that? :O

Answer (score 2):

If you need the punctuation character to repeat itself, change `[[:punct:]]{2}` to `([[:punct:]])\1`:

```
.*^(?=.*[[:lower:]]{2})(?=.*[[:upper:]])(?=.*[[:digit:]])(?=.*([[:punct:]])\1$).*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/SCCasE/1